# error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item when building sp_io

Tags: build

I am getting the following errors when building sp_io for our blockchain runtime.

```
 error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`
      --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/814752f/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:1633:1
       |
  1633 | pub fn panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       |
       = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `parity_scale_codec` depends on)
       = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /home/aibrayanov/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-02-19-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-d9a8e4ca4a56d589.rlib
       = note: second definition in the local crate (`sp_io`)

  error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `oom`
      --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/814752f/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:1649:1
       |
  1649 | pub fn oom(_: core::alloc::Layout) -> ! {
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       |
       = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `parity_scale_codec` depends on)
       = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /home/aibrayanov/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-02-19-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-d9a8e4ca4a56d589.rlib
       = note: second definition in the local crate (`sp_io`)

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
```

I tried to enable `default-features = std` and add`#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]` where relavant but I continue to get the same errors. Here is a copy of my Cargo.toml file (full runtime code can be found [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/feature/evm-precompile-mock))

```
[package]
name = "metaverse-runtime-common"
description = "Common code shared between runtimes"
version = "0.0.1"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
impl-trait-for-tuples = { version = "0.2.1", default-features = false }
log = { version = "0.4", default-features = false }
num_enum = { version = "0.5.3", default-features = false }
hex-literal = { version = "0.3.1", default-features = false }

# Substrate
frame-support = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
frame-system = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-collective = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-balances = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-timestamp = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-scheduler = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
sp-core = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
sp-runtime = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
sp-std = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
sp-io = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
# EVM pallets
pallet-evm = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-ethereum = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-base-fee = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-test-vector-support = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-precompile-blake2 = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-precompile-bn128 = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-precompile-dispatch = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-precompile-ed25519 = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-precompile-modexp = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-precompile-sha3fips = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
pallet-evm-precompile-simple = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }
fp-evm = { git = "https://github.com/justinphamnz/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }

# external crates - orml packages
orml-currencies = { git = "https://github.com/bit-country/open-runtime-module-library", branch = "v-9.24", default-features = false }
orml-tokens = { git = "https://github.com/bit-country/open-runtime-module-library", branch = "v-9.24", default-features = false }
orml-traits = { git = "https://github.com/bit-country/open-runtime-module-library", branch = "v-9.24", default-features = false }
orml-nft = { git = "https://github.com/bit-country/open-runtime-module-library", branch = "v-9.24", default-features = false }
orml-oracle = { git = "https://github.com/bit-country/open-runtime-module-library", branch = "v-9.24", default-features = false }
# metaverse dependencies
primitives = { package = "bit-country-primitives", path = "../../primitives/metaverse", default-features = false }
core-primitives = { path = "../../traits/core-primitives", default-features = false }
auction-manager = { package = "auction-manager", path = "../../traits/auction-manager", default-features = false }
metaverse = { package = "pallet-metaverse", path = "../../pallets/metaverse", default-features = false }
estate = { package = "pallet-estate", path = "../../pallets/estate", default-features = false }
evm-mapping = { package = "pallet-evm-mapping", path = "../../pallets/evm-mapping", default-features = false }
nft = { package = "pallet-nft", path = "../../pallets/nft", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
continuum = { package = "pallet-continuum", path = "../../pallets/continuum", version = "0.0.1", default-features = false }
auction = { package = "pallet-auction", path = "../../pallets/auction", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
currencies = { package = "currencies", path = "../../pallets/currencies", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
mining = { package = "pallet-mining", path = "../../pallets/mining", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
governance = { package = "pallet-governance", path = "../../pallets/governance", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
crowdloan = { package = "pallet-crowdloan", path = "../../pallets/crowdloan", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
economy = { package = "pallet-economy", path = "../../pallets/economy", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
emergency = { package = "pallet-emergency", path = "../../pallets/emergency", version = "2.0.0-rc6", default-features = false }
precompile-utils = { path = "../../primitives/precompiles", default-features = false }
precompile-utils-macro = {path = "../../primitives/precompiles/macro", default-features = false }
[build-dependencies]
substrate-wasm-builder = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24", default-features = false }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "pallet-evm/std",
    "fp-evm/std",
    "pallet-ethereum/std",
    "pallet-evm-precompile-blake2/std",
    "pallet-evm-precompile-simple/std",
    "pallet-evm-precompile-bn128/std",
    "pallet-evm-precompile-dispatch/std",
    "pallet-evm-precompile-ed25519/std",
    "pallet-evm-precompile-modexp/std",
    "pallet-evm-precompile-sha3fips/std",
    "orml-currencies/std",
    "orml-tokens/std",
    "orml-nft/std",
    "orml-oracle/std",
    "orml-traits/std",
    "primitives/std",
    "metaverse/std",
    "auction-manager/std",
    "auction/std",
    "estate/std",
    "nft/std",
    "continuum/std",
    "currencies/std",
    "mining/std",
    "evm-mapping/std",
    "governance/std",
    "crowdloan/std",
    "economy/std",
    "emergency/std",
    "precompile-utils/std",
    "sp-io/std",
    "sp-std/std",
    "sp-core/std",
    "sp-runtime/std",
    "pallet-balances/std",
    "pallet-collective/std",
    "pallet-timestamp/std",
    "pallet-scheduler/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-support/std",
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common cause of this type of error is the leaking of `std` features.

You should check if `sp-io` already included in default `std` (including other dependencies that may use `sp-io`).