# Error when compiling a contract using the XCM chain extension

Tags: smart-contract, xcm, chain-extension, contracts

I'm trying to implement this [xcm chain extension mvp](https://github.com/paritytech/pallet-contracts-xcm) to send a XCM call from a simple contract.

The problem i'm facing is when i try to compile the contract with the given [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/paritytech/pallet-contracts-xcm/blob/master/ink/Cargo.toml), i get the following compilation error:

```
➜  ink git:(master) ✗ cargo +nightly contract build

....

error: the `#[global_allocator]` in ink_allocator conflicts with global allocator in: sp_io

error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`.
  |
  = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `ink_env` (which `flipper` depends on)
  = note: first definition in `ink_env` loaded from /Users/hectorb/blockchain/pallet-contracts-xcm/ink/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libink_env-0acca4fc7a95b368.rlib
  = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/hectorb/blockchain/pallet-contracts-xcm/ink/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-7276ad9650247190.rlib, /Users/hectorb/blockchain/pallet-contracts-xcm/ink/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-7276ad9650247190.rmeta

error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `oom`.
  |
  = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `ink_allocator` (which `ink_env` depends on)
  = note: first definition in `ink_allocator` loaded from /Users/hectorb/blockchain/pallet-contracts-xcm/ink/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libink_allocator-f7c621310e573610.rlib, /Users/hectorb/blockchain/pallet-contracts-xcm/ink/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libink_allocator-f7c621310e573610.rmeta
  = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/hectorb/blockchain/pallet-contracts-xcm/ink/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-7276ad9650247190.rlib, /Users/hectorb/blockchain/pallet-contracts-xcm/ink/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-7276ad9650247190.rmeta

error: could not compile `extension-xcm` due to 3 previous errors
```

Is there anything i'm not taking into account when building the contract? I have tried with many variants adding the xcm crate dependency from a new project using `cargo contract new` ..., but the error is the same.

Also it would be nice to know if there is there any working example of this extension where i can take references?

Github issue: https://github.com/paritytech/pallet-contracts-xcm/issues/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error\[E0152\]: found duplicate lang item when building sp\_io](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/errore0152-found-duplicate-lang-item-when-building-sp-io)

Comment: not exactly because in contracts the sp_io is not directly imported, so i suppose there is a conflict when bringing the xcm with ink.

Answer (score 6):

The `xcm` crate at some point imports the `sp-io` that  contains its own implementation of the allocator making conflicts with the global_allocator of ink!

This can be solved importing the `sp-io` as well and use a set of specific features that explicitly excludes th:

`sp-io = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.30", default-features = false, features = ["disable_panic_handler", "disable_oom", "disable_allocator"] }`